# bash: rename a file based on a regex

Tags: regex, linux

I have a file named `/tmp/foo_primary.bar` by default or any other filename a user specified.

How can I rename the file (variable) using bash so that if it contains the string `primary` it will change to `secondary` and if not, just append `_secondary`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, a pattern will do:

```
#!/bin/bash
filepath=$1
if [[ $filepath != */* ]] ; then # File in PWD.
    filepath=./$filepath
fi
filename=${filepath##*/}

if [[ $filename = *primary* ]] ; then
    newname=${filename/primary/secondary}
else
    newname=$filename'_secondary'
fi

mv "$filepath" "${filepath%/*}"/"$newname"
```

Check "Parameter expansion" in `man bash` for explanations of the `${...}` constructs.